# What is SOURCESNAPSHOTCONTENT field represents in kubeclt get volumesnapshots output?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I got the following output for the command `oc get volumesnapshots`. I am interested to know what is `SOURCESNAPSHOTCONTENT` filed? How can I populate this field?

```
[root@oc-w3 independent]# oc get volumesnapshot
NAME    READYTOUSE   SOURCEPVC   SOURCESNAPSHOTCONTENT   RESTORESIZE   SNAPSHOTCLASS   SNAPSHOTCONTENT                                    CREATIONTIME   AGE
snap1   true         pvcfset3                            0             snapclass1      snapcontent-14adee62-d7c7-4c15-9d2e-f30614cfdd2f   <invalid>      4m33s
snap2   true         pvcfset3                            0             snapclass1      snapcontent-36ecbb4b-8d8e-4914-989d-49c78000dd8c   <invalid>      5s
```

Comment: You are asking what does `Source Snapshot Constant` means in OpenShift or what is the equivalent in Kubernetes?

Comment: It is the same output in openshift and kubernetes.